# Using window object to update DIV with JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON file that I'm trying to pull data from to update a div every 5 seconds.

JSON File:

`{"playersOnline":0,"version":"1.9.2"}`

JavaScript:

```
 var checkServerInfo = function(){
        // Get Info From JSON File
        $.getJSON('data.json', function(results) {
            window.playerName = new results[0].serverStatus;
        });             
        // Reload Every 5 Seconds
        setTimeout(checkServerInfo(),5000);
    };
    $(document).ready( checkServerInfo() );
```

If I replace the window object with `document.write(results.playerName);` it writes out the JSON data to the page.

Comment: I don't see a question here?

Comment: You're just setting the `window.playerName` variable; you have to actually do something with it if you want to have it visible in the page. Also note that you don't need the `new` keyword before accessing the `results`. Finally, the JSON you've shown doesn't appear to be an array nor does it have a `serverStatus` property. If you could actually give some details about what it is you're trying to do and why this doesn't work, it would be a good start.

Comment: Note that you're calling `setTimeout` on the *result* of calling `checkServerInfo`. If you want to actually call `checkServerInfo` every 5 seconds (or so), you'd want `setTimeout(checkServerInfo, 5000)`

Comment: Also `setTimeout` should be inside the callback function

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help...

```
 var checkServerInfo = function(){
        // Get Info From JSON File
       $.getJSON('data.json', function(results) {
           window.playerName = results.playersOnline;
           document.getElementById("whereDoYouWantToDisplayThis").innerHTML = window.playerName;
       });             
 };
 $(document).ready( function(){
    setInterval(checkServerInfo,5000);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank You, I tried the following and it's working.

```
var checkServerInfo = function(){

    // Get Info From JSON File
    $.getJSON('data.json', function(jsondata) {
        $('#autoUpdateServerPlayersOnline').html(jsondata.playersOnline);
    }); 

    // Reload Every 5 Seconds
    setTimeout(checkServerInfo,5000);

};  

$(document).ready( checkServerInfo() );
```